# What does "class example;" mean in a Header File?

Tags: c++, class, oop, syntax, header-files

I've a question about something what really confuses me!

Let's watch this code righ here:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <iostream>

class example;
class anything_else;

class A {
      public:
           A();
};

...
```

What does `class example;` and `class anything_else;` mean,
while `class A {};` gets declared? Inside the CPP File i saw definitions like `void example::release() { ... }` and so on...

I'm really confused, does anyone have a example with `class example;` ... ?

Comment: It's a [forward declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) of the class

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense! Are forward declarations still important these days?

Comment: It's so you can reference the forward declared class before it's been defined. It should be noted that if referenced before defined, it will be an incomplete type. ( i.e. you can only declare pointer or reference types of the forward declared class before it's defined )

Comment: @Lazcano: What makes you think that forward declarations are less important "these days"?

Comment: The forward declaration lets you declare (and use to a small extent) pointers and references to the class with out having the full declaration.  This can be important in situations where you might have a circular relationship between classes (which is generally something to avoid if possible) and in interfaces where implementation details should be hidden to permit loose coupling between the client and implementation of the interface.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I seem to be fighting a lost battle here, but why does everyone insist on calling the class definition a class declaration or a "full declaration"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does `class example;` and `class anything_else;` mean

They are declarations of the classes `example` and `anything_else`. They tell the compiler that those are valid class names. This kind of declaration is informally referred to as "forward declaration".

> while `class A {};` gets declared?

`class A` gets *defined*.

> Inside the CPP File i saw definitions like `void example::release() { ... }` and so on...

That's the definition of the function `example::release`.

Somewhere in the definition of `example`, there's the declaration of the function:

```
class example
{
// ...
    void release(); // declaration
};
```

If `example` is only declared and not defined, then the definition of `example::release` results in a compilation error.

Comment: It makes sense now! Thank you really much! (:

Answer (score 2):

if you want to have member variables of a type that have not yet been included you do a **forward declaration** of the type.

```
class X;
```

forward declares the class X so you can have a. e.g. a pointer to that class in our class declaration.

```
class Y
{
...
  X* p;
};
```

later you must supply the definition of the class somewhere in your .cpp file.

Comment: `class Y { /* ... */ };` is not a class declaration but a class definition.

Comment: Thanks! :) I still need to learn about "definition" and "declaration"

Comment: @ChristianHackl well it depends what's in the class, if you have only inline definitions of your functions then yes, it is a definition. but if you supply the definitions in a .cpp file then it is a declaration. e.g. class Y { public: Y(); }; is a declaration in .cpp Y:Y() { .. } definition

Comment: @AndersK.: No, `class Y { /* ... */ };` is always a definition, regardless of what members are specified. See for example §3.1/2, especially the list of examples.

Comment: @ChristianHackl you may be right, i don't have so much use of terminology when i program